# VMware Consolidated Backup - Availability in Essentials Bundle

Tags: vmware-esx

I would like to know whether VCB is available in the essentials bundle version or I have to install the standard or advanced versions of ESX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of ESX you mean but if you're talking about vSphere/v4 then 'Data Protection' features come with every version except 'Essentials' and 'Standard'.